# SQL - Displaying names instead of ID

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables

> **rankID | name**
>
> - 1   |  new
> - 2   | learner
> - 3   | experienced
> - 4   | pro

And another with all the user info and passwords and stuff

> **id | username | rankID**
>
> - 1 | hello | 3
> - 2 | hey | 3

I have come so far so I can display their rank number, but I want to display the rank name. How can I do that? I have tried a lot of things but I'm not so good at sql and the php part of it.

This is the code I use to display the rank number

```
//Get rankID
$query = "SELECT rankID FROM users WHERE id = '$userId'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$rank = $row['rankID'];
```

And to display the rank number:

```
Rank: <?php echo $rank; ?>
```

Comment: `SELECT rank.name as rank_name,users.rankID as rankID from users LEFT JOIN rank ON rank.rankID = users.rankID WHERE id = '$userId'`. AND THEN `$rank = $row['rankID'];$rank_name = $row['rank_name'];`

Comment: OR `select name from Ranks where rankid in(select rankid from users where id=$userId)`

Comment: `select name from Ranks as a where EXISTS (select b.rankID from users as b where id=$userId and a.rankID=b.rankID);`

Comment: I got it to work!
Now I'm using this query code:    $query = "SELECT ranks.rank_name as rank_name,users.rankID as rankID from users LEFT JOIN ranks ON ranks.rankID = users.rankID WHERE id = '$userId'";
BTW, I changed the "name" column to "rank_name"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple `JOIN` query :-

```
"SELECT rank.name as rank_name,users.rankID as rankID from users LEFT JOIN rank ON rank.rankID = users.rankID WHERE id = '$userId'"
```

And then After:-

```
$query = "SELECT rank.name as rank_name,users.rankID as rankID from users LEFT JOIN rank ON rank.rankID = users.rankID WHERE id = '$userId'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Do:-

```
$rank = $row['rankID'];
$rank_name = $row['rank_name'];

Rank: <?php echo $rank; ?>
RankName: <?php echo $rank_name; ?>
```

Or

```
$rank_data = $row;
Rank: <?php echo $rank_data['rankID']; ?>
RankName: <?php echo $rank_data['rank_name']; ?>
```

Not:- lot of other possible ways are there which are listed by other programmers in comment and answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

//Get datas

```
$query = "SELECT rankID, name FROM users WHERE id = '$userId'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$rank = $row['rankID'];
$rank = $row['name'];
```

And to display the datas:

```
Rank: <?php echo $rank; ?>
Name: <?php echo $name; ?>
```

Comment: Did you check before making this query?

Answer (score 0):

Hope so this should make a trick for you.

```
$query = "SELECT rankID FROM users WHERE id = '".$userId."'";
$result = $conn->query($query);
$count = $result->num_rows;
if($count==0)
{
   return false;
}
else
{
     $rows=[];
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
     {
        $rows[] = $row;
     }
     return $rows;
}
```

Comment: As per the Procedure of mysqli i have done that. Hope so if it works for you in Join Query. Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code

```
$query = "SELECT name FROM users as u JOIN rank as r ON r.rankID = u.rankID WHERE u.id = '$userId'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$name = $row['name'];


Name: <?php echo $name; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
//Get rankID
$query = "SELECT rankID, rank.name AS rank_name FROM rank, users WHERE id = '$userId' and users.rankid = rank.rankid";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$rank = $row['rank_name'];
echo $rank;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to get data from two different table.You need join query.
Here is your query which will solve your proble definitely :

```
$q="select a.name,b.rankID from rankname as a INNER JOIN user as b
ON a.rankID = b.rankID";
```

For more know about How to join two tables see this:http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-using-joins.htm

Hope this will help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
//Get rankID
$query = "SELECT r.name as rank_name FROM rank as r inner join users as u on r.rankID = u.rankID WHERE u.id = '$userId'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$rank = $row['rank_name'];

echo 'Rank: '. $rank;
```